# How to hide a UITableView cell upon an UISwitch ValueChanged event?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiswitch

Im trying to hide a cell in a UITableView upon a value changed event received from an UISwitch.

Heres my current IBAction for this. It does actually work, but somehow only after the third time the UI Switch was pressed by the user.  I have no idea why?

```
- (IBAction) TogglePasswordCell : (id) sender
{
// get PasswordCell
UITableViewCell *pwdcell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PasswordCell"];

// check uiswitch status
if(toggle_savepass.on)
{
    // hide pwd cell
    pwdcell.hidden = NO;
}
else
{
    // show pwd cell
    pwdcell.hidden = YES;
}

// reload tableview
[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: You should probably obtain a reference to the cell by using UITableView's `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, rather than attempting to use dequeue.

Comment: On the assumption that your password cell is the last cell in the section, I have generally found it easier to change the value that will be returned from `numberOfRowsInSection:` after reloading the tableview. In this way, TogglePasswordCell just becomes `[self.tableView reloadData]`, and `numberOfRowsInSection:` contains `return (toggle_savepass.on ? 5 : 4)` (substituting how many rows there are in that section. This works for static and dynamic tables